# How to save Information of user in React after user login

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I write a small app with React and back-end is PHP. I have 2 type user in database (admin and student). After user login, I save information in session Storage like that ( user: { username:'abcxyz123', role: 'admin' } ). The component render based user.role. This working good. But If I open DevTools and change user.role, my app will wrong render (because user.role is very simple text). How can I avoid this ??? My code is look like that.

```
class MyApp extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: (window.sessionStorage.user)
                   ? JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.user) 
                   : false,
    };
}

checkUserToLogin = (e) => {

    if( loginSuccess ){
        // return data of user in variable finalData
        // finalData = { username:'abcxyz123', role: 'admin' }
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(finalData));
        this.setState({ user: JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.user) });
    }
}

render() {

    const {
        user
    } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
             <form onSubmit={ this.checkUserToLogin }>
                  <input type="text" />
                  <input type="password" />
                  <button type="submit"> Login </button>
             </form>
             {/*Component will render based props user.role */}
             <Component user={user} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

I can't change my database. The data of role always **'admin'** or **'student'**.

Comment: You should save that vital information in a database. Like, when you register a new user, it assings it a default role, "student". And you just need any backend language + any React AJAX technology to check its value when you're going to display certain info.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence `But If I open DevTools and change user.role, my app will wrong render`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a check is done from your backend on every authenticated action, it shouldn't be a problem.

### What I think you do wrong

I think you send authenticated information to the front and let it handle if they should be shown or not. Which is really bad. Every informations sent in request can possibly be read, even if it's not render in DOM. The php backend should filter information based on database role.

### The solution

Only keep a token or something that authenticates your front user in its XHR request. JWT is a really great way to do it cause it can not be mutate from the front.
Handle the render or not of admin action but continue to check it in every backend request.
If the information are changed by a malicious user, it's going to be kick from backend and you don't care if the front is broken for him.

### To go further

It can be interesting too to keep this token and information in a global context. For example you can use [React.Context](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-your-first-app-with-reacts-context-api) or [Redux](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/login-using-react-redux-redux-saga-86b26c8180e) and synchronise it with your local storage.
So you don't need to go through props driling with your user data.